# Calculating how long does a hare remain stationary in a race

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I'm solving book exercises - there's a classic problem involving a hare and a tortoise. This is what I did, but apparently the final answer is wrong.

---

Basically it's a 1000m race, both animals have a constant speed (hare at 8m/s and tortoise at 0.2m/s). The hare runs 800m and then stops to tease the tortoise. Then, at some point in the future, the hare resumes and both animals finish at the same time.

> (a) How far is the tortoise from the finish line when the hare
>   resumes the race?

Well, since both animals finish at the same time, I just need to find out how long it takes the hare to finish the remaining 200m and then check how much distance could the tortoise cover in that time.

So

$$\frac{200\text{m}}{8\text{m/s}} = 25\text{s}$$

Meaning that the tortoise could cover barely

$$25\text{s}\cdot0.2\text{m/s} = 5\text{m}$$

This appears to be correct according to the book.

> (b) For how long in time was the hare stationary?

The hare runs $800\text{m}$ in $8$ seconds, so the tortoise barely covered $1.6\text{m}$ in that time. Since the hare restarts when the tortoise is $5\text{m}$ away from the finish line, it must have waited until the tortoise covered another $(1000 - 5 - 1.6) = 993.4$ meters, which takes $993.4 / 0.2 = 4967$ seconds.

Well apparently that's **wrong**. The book says the answer is just "$4.88$" (doesn't even mention the units, but even if that were minutes or hours it doesn't match).

What did I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter when the hare stopped. If he had stopped right before the finish line you would have the same result. So the question is - how much longer does it take the tortoise to cover the course? The hare has to start again *after* the tortoise passed him, in your formulation of the problem. Otherwise he will not arrive at the same time.

You are wrong when you say the hare runs 800 m in 8 seconds - he runs 8 m/s so it takes him 100 seconds to run 800 meters. Perhaps that's all the fix you need.

But I would do part 2 differently. Calculate the total time it takes the hare and the tortoise respectively. The difference in time is how long the hare waited. I make it 5000-125 = 4875 seconds, or 4.88 ks. Which is a rather unusual unit.